# Eigenstates in hexagonal well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

I am currently solving the 2D Schrödinger Equation Numerically for a hexagonal well. The modulus squared of the first four eigenstates I find are shown on the attached picture (please comment if they look correct). [image]

Now my question is: Should there not be a 6-fold degeneracy due to the 6-fold symmetry of the hexagon? My intuition tells me this but on the other hand it sounds weird since in general there would be an N-fold degeneracy for a symmetric polygon of N sides, which is obviously absurd. Where does my logic fail?

Comment: It seems additional insight would be gained if you compared the eigenvalues of your 2nd and 3rd solution (with two lobes).  I suspect the eigenvalues are identical since they can be rotated one into the other by a group element.  Moreover I'll bet there is probably a third solution with this energy, so then a sum of all these would also be a solution and would be be intuitively closer to the 6-fold symmetry of your well.  Ditto for the solution with 4 lobes.  The choice of phase of eigenvectors in the degenerate subspace is probably why not all solutions appear.

Comment: Those two aren't rotated by an element of the group. Connecting vertices vs edges. But yes they should be each part of bigger multiplets.

Comment: @AHusain good catch but clearly yes they must be part of a degenerate multiplet.

Answer (score 2):

Since the Hamiltonian is invariant under a unitary representstion of the symmetry group, you can conclude that every eigenspace of the Hamiltonian is invariant and  supports a representation of that group. However nothing implies that the dimension of the eigenspace is equal to the number of elements of the group. For instance it could be one-dimensional because the only (up factors)  eigenvector  is invariant under the action of the group.

More generally, the action of the symmetry group on an eigenvector can always be defined as a  linear combination of a finite set of eigenvectors with the same eigenvalue. Think of the hydrogen atom, for a given  value of the energy we have a finite dimensional eigenspage even if the symmetry group $SO(3)$ contains a continuous infinity of elements. This infinity corresponds to the infinite number  of possible  linear combinations of a finite number of eigenvectors forming the base of the given eigenspace of the Hamiltonian.

Comment: Namely that first picture you have is such a singlet.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the paper by Cureton and Kuttler (Journal of Sound and Vibration 220, 83-98 (1999))
in which the real counterpart of the Schroedinger Equation is considered. There EIGHT classes os symmetries appear which I'm sure are respected when going to the complex version.